# What is the Tales from the Dark Side episode where a teenager has a literal conniption over getting one dollar to eat at Dairy Queen?

Tags: story-identification, tv, horror

I'm not even sure if it's from *Tales From the Dark Side*, but I imagine it would be since it fits the style. In this episode, a middle class mother has a McGuffin that turns her figures of speech into literal occurrences. Near the end of the episode, she says, "Help! He's having a conniption over a dollar!" Sure enough, the teenager asking for money at the doorstep starts shaking violently until he hits the ground. The episode concludes when the mother uses the McGuffin to wish herself away from the world so she can't hurt anybody else.

Answer (score 6):

I think the story is "A Serpent's Tooth". It is episode 8 of season 3 of Tales from the Dark Side.

From wikipedia

> A controlling mother is given the title item by a friend, causing her warnings and metaphors to come true. This forces her children to obey her; her son studies to be a dentist instead of agriculture, while her daughter is forced to dress in outdated and feminine styled clothes. After she accidentally turns her daughter's boyfriend into a slice of bread, her children snap at her. The episode ends with the mother now a pilar of salt after saying to be turned into one if she was a terrible mother.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That's the episode I've been looking for. :)

Comment: @Garrison please accept the answer.